# Bootstrap | Make col span full height of row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make my bootstrap column span the full height of a row. The issue i am having is that I cannot get it to change size.

currently my HTML looks like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
         <!-- Content removed for demo | large form here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `col-sm-11` contains a form which is x height (around 400/500px)

the `col-sm-1` contains no content but I want to make it 100% height so it matches the form next to it. How do I go about doing this

### Attempts

I have tried applying `height 100%` to that column but it remains the same.

I have also tried setting a static amount like `300px` but this just pushes the form down. and i need it to be 100% anyway

Comment: Post the code with content inside i.e. the form element.

Comment: it adds way to much code its a very large form, also it doesn't matter about the form it does the same whether its a form or multiple h1's for example

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703334/bootstrap-equal-height-colums

Comment: or this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height?rq=1

Comment: the row row-eq-height doesnt appear to be making any difference to my code :S

Comment: @Kieranmv95 try the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629477/bootstrap-3-panel-100-height-inside-column/32630031#32630031

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of for you to do this is to use one line of jQuery, if possible.

Add a class, two separate ones, to each of your two columns.

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col1">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-11 col2">
</div>
```

In jQuery, simply add this line of code at the top of your $(document).ready(function() {...});

```
$('.col1').height($('.col2').height());
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/12678/)

**Note**: I made your col-sm's col-xs's so that you could see it in JSFiddle without resizing.

**Note #2**: You may want to put the line of jQuery inside of a $(window).resize(function() {...}); so that it changes with the responsiveness.